# jQuery carousel - how to automate slide

Tags: jquery, carousel

I've added this basic carousel to a site but cannot find code anywhere which will add a slide effect. Currently you have to click on the circles to move through the slides, but I'd like this to be automatic after 10 seconds for example.

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/basic/

Any help would be appreciated. I'm a beginner with jQuery so go easy on me please.

Comment: setInterval(function(){$('.jcarousel-control-next').click();}, 3000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the [`Autoscroll plugin`](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/plugins/autoscroll/).

> The jCarousel Autoscroll Plugin provides autoscrolling support for
>   jCarousel.

Configuration: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/plugins/autoscroll/reference/configuration.html

Code:

```
$(function () {

    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel();

    $('.jcarousel').jcarouselAutoscroll({
        interval: 1000,
        target: '+=1'
    })
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/2Kspn/

### Update

For infinite loop carousel use [`wrap`](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/configuration.html#wrap) option to `circular`:

> Specifies whether to wrap at the first or last item (or both) and jump
>   back to the start/end. Options are "first", "last", "both" or
>   "circular" as string.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/2Kspn/1/

Comment: Okay, thank you for replying.I have added this in which has got it working - however it only works from slides 1 - 4 then it stops. From 4, it doesn't start from the beginning again! Any advice?

Comment: That didn't work but I've tested your jsfiddle adding this:  .jcarouselPagination();
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel({wrap:"last"}).jcarouselAutoscroll();

Answer (score 0):

Check [Autoscroll plugin](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/plugins/autoscroll/reference/installation.html)

```
$(function() {
    $('.jcarousel')
        .jcarousel({
            // Core configuration goes here
        })
        .jcarouselAutoscroll({
            interval: 3000,
            target: '+=1',
            autostart: true
        })
    ;
});
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for replying.I have added this in which has got it working - however it only works from slides 1 - 4 then it stops. From 4, it doesn't start from the beginning again! Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this plugin of jcarousel will help you do your work.
[Autoscroll Plugin](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/plugins/autoscroll/)